# How do I display a number between 1 and 100 and show if the number is out of the boundary?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash/  

echo "Choose a number between 1 and 100"  
read num  
num=num  
echo  
if [ $num -lt 100 -o -gt 1 ]; then  
       echo "You chose $num"  
elif [ $num -gt 100 -o -lt 1 ]; then  
       echo "you chose a number outside of the boundary"  
fi
```

Comment: Some prose around the code would be useful. As-is, you have a title that sounds like a spec, and a pile of code. Show some inputs outputs and errors.

Answer (score 4):

With POSIX sh syntax:

```
#! /bin/sh - 

printf 'Choose a decimal integer number between 1 and 100: '
IFS= read -r num

die() {
  printf >&2 '%s\n' "$@"
  exit 1
}
case $num in
  ("" | - | *[!0123456789-]* | ?*-*)
    die "$num is not a valid decimal integer number";;
  (*[123456789]??*)
    die "You chose a number outside the boundaries"
esac

if [ "$num" -lt 1 ] || [ "$num" -gt 100 ]; then  
  die "You chose a number outside the boundaries"
fi

echo "You chose $num"
```

- *number* is ambiguous. `0xAA`, `MMXVIII`, `¾`, `010`, `1.4e+4`, `infinity` are all numbers by some definition of *number*. Many POSIX-like shells, including `bash` only support decimal integers in their `[` builtin (and decimal, octal, hexadecimal in their arithmetic expressions). It's better to qualify exactly what type of number you want. Here decimal integer for instance.
- [Using arbitrary strings in an arithmetic expression and in some shells in the `[` command is a command injection vulnerability](/a/172109). So you'd want to check that the input number looks like a number first.
- [`IFS= read -r line` is the syntax to read one line of input](/q/209123) (though here the `$IFS`-stripping and line continuation handling of `read num` would probably be OK).
- [parameter expansions need to be quoted in Bourne-like shells](/q/171346)
- You had a flaw in your logic. You used *or* instead of *and* operator.  All decimal numbers are either greater than 1 *or* less than 100.
- The `-o` and `-a` `[` operators are deprecated as they make for test expressions that can't be interpreted reliably. While here, it wouldn't be a problem once we've made sure the arguments are decimal integer numbers, they are best avoided. It's better to use several `[` invocations separated by `&&` or `||` shell operators.
- It's better to output error messages on stderr (`>&2`) and exit with a non-zero exit status upon failure.
- Most shells use the compiler's native integer data types for their integer operators. For most shells on most systems, 2<sup>64</sup>+50 for instance (18446744073709551666) would be too big for that internal representation. Depending on the shell's `[` implementation, it would be either not recognised as a number (bash, dash, yash), truncated to 19 digits with a warning (zsh), approximated as a float number (ksh93), or wrapped (so regarded as the same as 50) (mksh). So you may find that `[ 18446744073709551666 -gt 0 ]` returns false, or that `[ 18446744073709551666 -le 100 ]` returns true. Hence the `*[123456789]??*` check for more than 3 digit numbers.
- note that if the user enters a NUL character as part of their input, the behaviour will vary between shells.

With `bash` specifically, you can make it slightly less awkward with:

```
#! /bin/bash - 

IFS= read -rp 'Choose a decimal integer number between 1 and 100: ' num

die() {
  printf >&2 '%s\n' "$@"
  exit 1
}
[[ $num =~ ^-?[0123456789]+$ ]] ||
  die "$num is not a valid decimal integer number"

[[ $num = *[123456789]??* ]] ||
  ((num < 1 || num > 100)) &&
  die "You chose a number outside the boundaries"

echo "You chose $num"
```

Comment: This answer is both useful and admirable, but perhaps it goes too far?

Answer (score 3):

Using the shell test:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -rp "Choose a number between 1 and 100: " num
echo  
if [ "$num" -le 100 -a "$num" -ge 1 ]; then  
       echo "You chose $num"  
else 
       echo "you chose a number outside of the boundary"  
fi
```

---

Using bash extended test:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -rp "Choose a number between 1 and 100: " num
echo  
if [[ "$num" -le 100 && "$num" -ge 1 ]]; then  
       echo "You chose $num"  
else
       echo "you chose a number outside of the boundary"  
fi
```

---

Using shell arithmetic:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -rp "Choose a number between 1 and 100: " num
echo  
if ((num<=100 && num>=1)); then  
       echo "You chose $num"  
else  
       echo "you chose a number outside of the boundary"  
fi
```

---

Note:  You are using `-o` for **or** but you seem to want `-a` for **and**.  With or only one condition needs to pass so the number could be -1 or 101.

Also the right hand side of the `-o` is like a whole new test so you need to reintroduce the variable on that side.  Additionally I'm just using `else` instead of the `elif` statement because if the number doesn't pass the first test there is no need to perform another test on it.

Comment: Note that the `[[ "$num" -le 100 && "$num" -ge 1 ]]` and `((num<=100 && num>=1))` ones can become command injection vulnerabilities. For instance, if the user enters `a[$(reboot)]`, it would run `reboot`. See [Security Implications of using unsanitized data in Shell Arithmetic evaluation](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/172103)

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd line below is a fatal typo, (probably was meant to be `num="$num"`), but the line would be unnecessary if it was correct.

```
read num
num=num
```

If the user inputs the number *"1"*, the 2nd line changes it to the non-numeric string *"num"*.  Which would break all the number bound checking thereafter.

To fix that, just delete the 2nd line.

Comment: `num="$num"` would not have been very useful. `((num = num))` or `let num=num` could have been more useful, for instance to turn `1+1` into `2` or `0xa` or `012` into `10` (would be a command injection vulnerability though).